# Change the UITableView separatorColor for a single UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone

I have a `UITableView` that uses a variety of custom `UITableViewCells`.

I'd like to be able to have one of these table cells appear with a different separator color than the rest of the other cells.

I know that `tableview.seperatorColor` updates the whole `tableView`. Is there a cell specific property I missing or another approach to doing this?

Thanks for any tips. Sorry if I am just spacing on something in the `UITableViewCell` class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Disclaimer - this worked for me *at the time* under my specific circumstances. It is not guaranteed to work, it appears to no longer work, and I now advise you subclass `UITableViewCell`.**

Came across this post when looking to set the `UITableView.separatorColor` differently across groups/sections in a grouped `UITableView`.

You don't necessarily need to subclass `UITableViewCell`. You can try setting `tableView.separatorColor` on each call to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

For example, if you want the separator to be visible with the default color in the first section, visible in the first row/cell of the second section, and invisible in the rest of the rows in the second section, you can do the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        tableView.separatorColor = nil;
        break;
    case 1:
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                tableView.separatorColor = nil;
                break;
            case 1:
                tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Super interesting. I appreciate you updating this. I had ended up doing setting up my own separators in my cell but this looks very promising and I'll give it a shot. I guess the value is checked every time a uitablecell is being setup anyway so no perf impact simply changing it.

Comment: Had occasion to face this issue again in another tableview. This approach works and avoids needing to drawing your own separator for each cell.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in iOS SDK 4.3. When I try it, the separators flickr as I scroll and end up randomly visible when I stop scrolling.

Comment: We are not guaranteed this hack works across different iOS versions since in the docs separatorColor is defined as a global property. It's unsafe.

Comment: This may work if the number of rows in the sections are heigh but it does not definitely work when the sections are small.

Comment: @nekno, I have also same case but i am not success with this code. My case is i have multiple section. Each section contain 6 Rows. I am just want to remove cell separator line into the first cell and wish to add separator line in other cell. is it possible?

Comment: Tableview Cell have a not any method to handle separator line property only for cell. They are effect the whole Table view property.

Answer (score 9):

The `tableView.separatorColor` is global across all cells.

If you want to further customize these colors, your best bet would be to set `separatorStyle` property to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`, and override `UITableViewCell`.

Then you can draw your own custom seperator in the `contentView` of the `Cell` and customize it.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from iOS 7 something like this seems to be working fine:

1. Set `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine` on your UITableView
2. For the cell that you want to change the separator color first hide the separator by changing the insets `cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 10000);`
3. Change the background color of the cell that should have different separator color `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];`

Now separator will have the same color as your cell's backgroundcolor. Note that all this can be set on your cell's xib file without any code. Also note that you probably want to change cell's contentView's background color to something different than default (probably white) so green color will appear only on the separator line.