# Hide UITableViewStyleGrouped separator at certain sections

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a grouped `UITableView` and I have only one cell at section 0. I just want to hide the separator at the first section. If I use `tableView.separator = [UIColor clearColor]`, it hides all separators. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question of [change separator color for single cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711855/change-the-uitableview-separatorcolor-for-a-single-uitableviewcell). Summary of that: separator color appears to be a global setting for UITableView. If you really wish to make it different, it appears that you will have to roll your own UITableViewCell subclass.

Answer (score 2):

While the original comment is generally the way to do this (roll your own subclass with a separator), iOS7 has given us a new pretty easy way to do it too.

With the addition of `separatorInsets` on tables in iOS7, `UITableViewCell` now has a `separatorInset` property. By giving it a large value larger than the size of the table (such as `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 320, 0, 0)`), you can effectively hide the separator by simply moving it off the screen.

The caveat is that the default, built-in views of a `UITableViewCell` rely on the separator inset for the horizontal alignment of its content (so the content would also be off the screen and invisible). The way to fix this would be to build your own subviews instead, or set the x origin of the default ones you are using in the `layoutSubviews` method of your `UITableViewCell` subclass.